# Ошибка System.InvalidOperationException C#

Tags: c#, api, rest

Пытаюсь реализовать простое api, столкнулся с непонятной проблемой, уже перерыл кучу информации как можно исправить, но в итоге ничего не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

Пример, как делал модели

```
namespace ManagementCompanyAPI.Models
{
    public class Catalog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public int MinCount { get; set; }
        public int MaxCount { get; set; }
        public string? Units { get; set; }
        public Company? Company { get; set; }
    }
```

DataConext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasKey(pc => new { pc.Id });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasKey(pc => new { pc.Id });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Company)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.Company);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasNoKey();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Location)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.Location);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Catalog>()
            .HasIndex(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Catalog>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Company)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.Company);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Price>()
            .HasKey(pc => new { pc.Id });
    }
```

'Company' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Location' because it is configured as a navigation.

Репозитория: https://github.com/artzse/ManagementCompanyAPI

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, у вас не правильно сконфигурирован внешний ключ `.HasForeignKey(p => p.Company)`. Решить проблему можно двумя способами:

1. Указать теневой ключ, в этом случае не надо менять модель

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Company)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("CompanyId");
```

2. Явно указать внешний ключ в модели

```
public class Catalog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public int MinCount { get; set; }
    public int MaxCount { get; set; }
    public string? Units { get; set; }
    public Company? Company { get; set; }

    //внешний ключ
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
}
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Company)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CompanyId);
```

Аналогичным способом, скорее всего решатся и остальные проблемы вашем конфиге. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many)